# Achieving a fixed frame-rate with varying scenes

Tags: opengl, 3d, models, frame-rate

I am working on an OpenGL 3D model viewer app for iOS.

I have to load, view and navigate extra detailled 3D models on an iPad. I hardly achieve 2 fps, if i load and navigate a very complex model. I tried some optimizations like view-frustum-culling, area in pixel space, back-face-culling etc but still i am unable to improve the frame rate.

I would like to set fixed frame-rate to some X fps for my app and drop-out all the objects which don't have enough time to render at run-time. I would like to know if there is any algorithm to achieve this fixed frame-rate. I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of dropping objects that do not have enough time is a very bad idea for an object viewer. Different devices (such as older hardware or different performance settings) will render your object differently and you'll never be able to view the complete object.

In games, there is often not enough time to do things completely on one frame, and the common solution for your problem is to time-slice the rendering.

What that that means in pseudo-code is the following:

```
while(running)
{
    if (cameraMoved())
    {
        clear();
        modelToDraw.resetVertices();
    }

    frameTimer.start()
    do
    {
        meshData = modelToDraw.selectNextVertices(10000);
        draw(meshData);
    } while (frameTimer.elapsed() < maxFrameTime);
}
```

Basically you don't clear your buffers and just render blocks of 10000 vertices until the frame timer runs out. On the next frame you just keep on rendering until you have drawn all vertices and the object is complete.

As soon as the current scene is invalidated (in the pseudo code this happens when the camera moves, but it might as well happen if you change any rendering setting (such as light properties, object location, etc.)), you clear the buffers and start rendering from the first 10000 vertices again.

This time slicing algorithm is demonstrated nicely in the [Brigade Path Tracing engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpT6MkCeP7Y): The longer the camera stays still, the better the correct solution is approximated. As soon as the camera moves, the buffers are cleared and the rendering starts anew.

A further improvement could be importance sampling: select the vertices that are the most important first. Split up the model in sections (using some space partitioning scheme such as an octree) and select the nodes that are the closest to the camera first, so that the most important vertices are drawn first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to drop objects only during navigation. Once scene gets static I can render everything inside view frustum. My model rendering already happens in a recursive tree structure. This tree is defined inside CAD file. Would you suggest should ditch this tree defined in CAD file and replace it with octree for rendering?

Comment: @user3228921: Creating a static scene with this approach is as simple as locking camera movement.
Creating an octree is not a requirement. I would suggest using brute-force (just traverse all vertices) or use the tree already present in the CAD, and see if the performance is acceptable. If not, you can look into different [space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Types_of_space_partitioning_data_structures) techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're most likely looking for and what I'd try as well would be something like this:

```
while (running) {
    clear();

    timer_start();

    for_each(stuff in stuff_to_draw) {
        draw(stuff);
        if (timer_elapsed() > frame_time)
            break;
    }

    display();
}
```

In this example, `stuff_to_draw` would be sorted by priority (and possibly distance). `frame_time` would be the time allowed per frame (leaving some room for final processing of the scene).

As an alternative, you could just adjust your level of detail or drawing distance based on the framerate, i.e. the higher the framerate, the further you draw your scene:

```
while (running) {
    clear();

    timer_start();

    for_each(stuff in stuff_to_draw) {
        draw(stuff);
    }

    if (timer_elapsed() > frame_time)
        reduce_drawing_distance();
    else
        increase_drawing_distance();

    display();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By 'drawing distance' You mean just by moving camera far from the object and draw will increase frame-rate? Or you suggest me to drop objects which are far from camera?

Comment: Dropping stuff being out of range (i.e. behind the drawing distance). Or in other words, downsize your view frustum to gain framerate.